# Rails 3: Defining two paths with different parameters for an action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller named users and index action in it. By default I have the path

```
get '/users' => 'users#index', :as => 'users'
```

Now I want to create one more path with a different parameter being passed

```
get '/users/:city' => 'users#index', :as => 'list_users'
```

But this gives as error, `No route matches {:controller=>"users"}`.

I ran rake routes and found the path I defined to be present over there but it doesn't works.

What shall be done to make this work.

Comment: which line of code gives you the `No route matches {:controller=>"users"}`  ?